# Element is not clickable - Error Getting while running Selenium testcases

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am getting following error while running selenium testcases.
Using the versions firefox 45 and selenium-server-standalone 2.52.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: **Element is not clickable at
>   point (62, 13.333328247070312). Other element would receive the click:**
>
> (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 21 milliseconds Build info: version:
>   '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42' System
>   info: host:
>   'mesos-wl-servicetest-8f2fe7b6-d8bd-429f-abfc-cf5d29242b38', ip:
>   '172.31.6.249', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '4.4.2-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_51' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false,
>   pageLoadStrategy=fast, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true,
>   version=45.1.0, platform=LINUX, nativeEvents=false,
>   acceptSslCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   pageLoadingStrategy=fast, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   d6ae5f7f-be19-4b79-b248-dfb034d6ce1c  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteExecuteMethod.execute(RemoteExecuteMethod.java:35)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteMouse.click(RemoteMouse.java:59)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.interactions.ClickAction.perform(ClickAction.java:37)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.interactions.CompositeAction.perform(CompositeAction.java:50)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.perform(Actions.java:373)

Comment: What's the code generating the error?  It looks like you have a click attempted before the element is ready for it?

Comment: Please post the java code where you're getting this error along with the HTML snippet of the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `JavascriptExecutor`

```
 WebElement el = driver.findElement....;
 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver
 executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
```

Hope it will help you to perform `click`...:)

Answer (score 0):

*JavascriptExecutor* click is an good option to avoid element is not clickable at point (xx,yy). Other element would receive the click.

ANother alternate that you can use is *explicit wait* for presence of that element

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions can be ..

```
1)Try to maximize the browser when you are working with resolutions greater than 1024x768. 
             driver.manage().window().maximize();
2) Using  Actions Class
             WebElement element = driver.findElement(By("element"));
             Actions action = new Actions(driver);
             action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
3) using JavaScriptExecutor
             WebElement el = driver.findElement(By("element"));
             JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver
             executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
```